# Python Pygame forces

Tags: python, pygame

I've been wanting to create a physics engine for my game, and decided I should first cover forces. I'm using pygame on python to accomplish this.

For example, I want to be able to program a force of a certain magnitude, that acts on an object. I haven't been able to think of any way to do this. After I get the basic strategy down, it should be easy to subtract magnitudes of forces and add all kinds of different properties. Here is my source code now:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Physics Engine')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = display_width / 2
y = display_height / 2


gameExit = False

def force():
    # force function
    # Code here

y_change = 0
x_change = 0

while not gameExit:



    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:  # check for key presses
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:  # left arrow turns left
                x_change = -10
                y_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:  # right arrow turns right
                x_change = 10
                y_change = 0


    y += y_change
    x += x_change

    print(x, y)

    gameDisplay.fill((255, 255, 255))
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, (255, 0, 0), [x, y, 30, 30])
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(25)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

As of now, it simply is a red square moving left and right. I want it to be that if I hold down the arrow key it moves, and when I release it stops. I've tried using a boolean in the event, but it doesn't seem to want to work.

I would like to implement a simple gravity factor.

Thanks so much for reading!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few points I can see.  Firstly, if you want an effect to occur while you hold a key down then you should query if that key is down, rather than just pressed.  Ignore KEYDOWN events and use http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed 
instead.  Secondly, you should define or use library classes for positions, velocities, etc... which will give you a concrete set of operations.

From there the basic idea is to query the keys, set this update's acceleration from that and gravity, set velocity by updating old velocity with acceleration, set position by updating old position with velocity, and repeat forever.

Answer (score 0):

When a force is applied, it adds an acceleration to the object in terms of the mass in the direction of the force.

First of all, I would suggest creating variables for your object's mass, x and y velocity and its x and y resultant force components. When a force is added to the object, it would be easier to add it in terms of its x and y components ( if you wanted the force to be defined with an angle and magnitude you could use `opposite = sin(angle) * hypotenuse` and `adjacent = cos(angle) * hypotenuse` to split the force into components. Careful though -- the `math` module uses radians, and `pygame` uses degrees ) .

To apply the force on the screen, you can use `force = mass * acceleration` to find the x and y accelerations on the object, and apply those changes to the x and y velocities of the object (that's your `x_change` and `y_change`). Then apply the x and y velocities to the position of the object.

If you want it to work in terms of meters and seconds, instead of pixels and frames, you'll need to work out conversions for that as well: just use your `clock.tick` value to work out frames per second, and you can make up a value for pixels per meter.

As for gravity, the force applied = mass * gravitational field strength (the gravitational field strength on earth is 9.81 Newtons / kilogram ). Using this formula, you can add gravity to your object like any other force. The acceleration due to gravity is always the same as the gravitational field strength though, which might be useful if no other vertical forces are being applied.